# Can't get the routes object in play framework to show my custom route

Tags: java, playframework

I'm attempting to do a reverse lookup on a route I've created.
The route is defined as such in my routes file:

```
POST    /login            controllers.Web.Application.authenticate
```

However, when I try to do a reverse on it in a form I made, I can't seem to find it. I'm attempting to do a reverse like this:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.login())) {
    rest of the form here...
}
```

However, the login appears in red in intellij and when attempting to run the program, I get the following error:

play.sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[value login is not a member of object controllers.routes]

I've attempted recompiling the project multiple times and looking around the docs, but it's just not working... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

As we discovered in the comments, the reverse router doesn't seem to like sub packages.  You should remove the `Web` part of your package, and move everything up a level, then change the code to be this:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.authenticate())) {
    rest of the form here...
}
```

---

Original answer:

You need to refer to the controller function, and not the name of the route, so it should look something like this:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.Web.Application.authenticate())) {
    rest of the form here...
}
```

Comment: That still doesn't work. I've tried using it as you've shown, as well as adding controllers between routes and Web, neither worked. In both cases, the element right after routes is red in the editor and returns the error: value Web is not a member of object controllers.routes.

Comment: @Etienne Try taking out the `.Web` part.  What is the package for your application controller?

Comment: I've tried removing the .Web part as well, same error except it's about Application when I do.
The package declaration for the application controller is: controllers.Web

Comment: Hmm maybe you could try getting rid of your `Web` package and move everything up one level?  In the documentation their example is just one level `action = routes.Application.submit` https://playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers

Comment: That actually worked! So the reverse routing can't inspect subpackages, that's kinda dumb. Anyways, thanks a lot for your help. If you want to update your answer, I'll accept it :)

Comment: Interesting, I did not know that either

Answer (score 2):

So, an interesting thing happened recently and I found a way to point to the original structure properly. To do so, rather than writing:

```
routes.Web.Application.authenticate()
```

As Tyler suggested, I was supposed to write:

```
Web.routes.Application.authenticate()
```

Which is totally counter-intuitive and all, but that allows me to use the original package structure.

Comment: This answers is valid till date :-)